# Installing Raspbian shrinks SD card

Tags: raspbian

When I install raspbian(raspbian-jessie-lite) on a 32 GB microSD card using Win32 Disk Imager the size of the sdcard shrinks to 60MB.

Why does that happend? How can I avoid this?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use a software called `H2test2` to test if the card is really 32GB and shows you the partition sizes too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really shrink the size of your SD card, it creates several partitions on the card, out of which only one is recognized by Windows (the 60MB boot partition). The rest is still there, but only visible to Operating Systems that can read ext3/ext4 file systems. The initial size of the main partition on the SD card will be limited though - once you boot into Raspbian you will need to use `sudo raspi-config` (or use the GUI from the Menu) to resize the root partition to utilize the full remaining space on your SD card.